# Why it Kotlin giving me the wrong Int value when converting from a String

Tags: android, kotlin

I have the following code:

```
newCode = "9780802412720"
val character = newCode[0]
val charInt = character.toInt()
```

What I'm expecting is that `chatInt == 9`, but what's happening is that `charInt == 57` instead. Why?

Here's a screenshot from Android Studio while debugging. Where is that 57 coming from?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll have to convert your `Char` to a `String` in order to convert it to a Digit. Otherwise, you will get the integer used to represent the `Char` internally.

**UPDATE: If you are using Kotlin 1.5 or higher**

Kotlin 1.5 introduced `Char.digitToInt()`, which does this conversion for you. You can even specify the radix, but it conveniently defaults to base 10.

```
character.digitToInt()
```

**Before Kotlin 1.5**

```
character.toString().toInt()
```

And you could define an extension function to make this cleaner:

```
fun Char.asDigit(): Int = this.toString().toInt()
println(character.asDigit())
```

Answer (score 4):

57 is the Ascii code for the character `9`.

To get the value 9 you need to use:

```
newCode[i] - '0'
```

This works because the Ascii digit characters are right next to each other in ascending order `'0'` is 48. In many languages, including Kotlin, the Characters are just numbers so basic mathematical operations work as normal.

Comment: This seems like a simple solution taking leverage of Kt types, it would be good to explain how this work

Comment: More accurately and precisely, 57 is the UTF-16 value for the UTF-16 code unit '9'.